# Center Align Cell Text in Vb.Net DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, formatting

I am working with DataGridView and there is a scenario that I have to show centered align text in selected columns, I have managed to set Header Center Align Text but with Row Cell and Conditions, I am unable to figure out how?

Suppose I have 4 Rows with 3 Columns,`ID ,Name,Type`, On the bases of `Type` column I want to show my data as given below picture,
[image]

In CellFormattingEvent I have managed to set different color scheme.

```
Private Sub grdDetailsNew_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles grdFruitDetailsNew.CellFormatting
    Try
        If e.RowIndex > -1 Then
            If grdDetailsNew.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                If grdDetailsNew.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Type").Value = 1 Then
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(253, 192, 97)
                    e.CellStyle.Font = New Font(e.CellStyle.Font.FontFamily, 17, FontStyle.Regular)
                ElseIf grdDetailsNew.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Type").Value = 2 Then
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 249, 237)
                    e.CellStyle.Font = New Font(e.CellStyle.Font.FontFamily, 16, FontStyle.Regular)
                Else
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
                    e.CellStyle.Font = New Font(e.CellStyle.Font.FontFamily, 15, FontStyle.Regular)
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteToLog(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub grdDetailsNew_CellPainting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles grdFruitDetailsNew.CellPainting
    Try

        If e.RowIndex > -1 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex > -1 Then
            If e.ColumnIndex = 2 AndAlso grdDetailsNew.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Type").Value = 1 Then
                e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add         `e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter` inside the cell formatting event. And remove it from the paint event.

eg:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    Dim type = CInt(CType(sender, DataGridView).Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("type").Value)
    If type = 1 andalso e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
End Sub
```

Comment: No, Not full Row but a certain column on certain condition

Comment: I've added an example which looks for the rows type field and reformats the first column if both = 1

Comment: Actually it appears you have the correct code in your paint event. Try moving it into the cell formatting handler instead.

Comment: Good, It worked , just moving the aligmnet line of text into Formatting Event.